# Cursor fetching performance in non UI thread

Tags: android

I've got a performance problem while fetching data from a cursor in `AsyncTaskLoader`. Testing in android API level 10. For example 2 classes with cursor - `TestFragmentUI` fetching data in UI thread and `TestFragment` fetching data in none `UI thread`.

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Object> {
...

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
...
}

public android.support.v4.content.Loader<Object> onCreateLoader(
            int id, Bundle args) {
    return new Loader(getActivity());
}

class Loader extends AsyncTaskLoader<Object> {


    public Loader(Context context) {
        super(context);     
    }
    public Object loadInBackground() {
        ...
        DataBaseHelper helper = new DataBaseHelper(getContext());
        SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Cursor data = database.rawQuery(String.format(SQL_LOAD, parametr), null);
        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            String number = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex("number"));
        }
        data.close();       
        Log.i(TAG, "load: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        ... 
    }
}
...
}
```

and

```
public class TestFragmentUI extends Fragment {
...

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
DataBaseHelper helper = new DataBaseHelper(getActivity());
SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getReadableDatabase();
...
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
Cursor data = database.rawQuery(String.format(SQL_LOAD, parametr), null);
while (data.moveToNext()) {
String number = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex("number"));
}
data.close();
Log.i(TAG, "load: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
...
}

...
}
```

In emulator `TestFragment` class output time that is 10 times slower than output `TestFragmentUI` and visually it is very noticeable.

Any ideas?

Comment: it could be slower(emulator not emulate/using dual/quadro cores/ht) but loading data in background is not for speed but for responsiveness

Comment: Also, everything is slower in the emulator than on a real device.  It may not even be noticeable if you run it on an actual android device.

Comment: so n00bman ...what you wana achive? becouse now you're only iterating the Cursor ...

Comment: This is only sample code. All I whana to do is to show data from datadase to user.

Answer (score 0):

use it on a real device (your phone) to test since emulators are slow

Comment: On a real device (I've got a DHD) 3-fold difference - still very big.

Comment: This isn't really an answer; try earning some more rep - commenting [requires 50](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) - and post remarks like these as a comment.

Comment: i didn't have 50 when i wrote this, that's why had to write it in this way... but now all good :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to change background process priority (Process.setThreadPriority) coz by default AsyncTask runs at background priority.